# Simple math library in Rust

Tags: mathematics, rust

So, I've tried to make a simple math library in Rust. What do you think about it?

```
const PRECISION: f64=512.; //Balance between speed and precision here.

fn ln(x:f64) -> f64 {
    let mut sum=0.;
    let epsilon=(x-1.)/(5.*PRECISION);
    let mut i=1.;
    while (epsilon>0. && i<x) || (epsilon<0. && i>x) {
        sum+=epsilon/i;
        i+=epsilon;
    }
    sum
}

fn exp(x:f64) -> f64 {
    let mut i=0.;
    let mut y=1.;
    let epsilon=x/PRECISION;
    while (epsilon>0. && i<x) || (epsilon<0. && i>x) {
        y+=epsilon*y;
        i+=epsilon;
    }
    y
}

fn arctan(x:f64) -> f64 {
    let mut sum=0.;
    let epsilon=x/PRECISION;
    let mut i=0.;
    while i<x {
        sum+=epsilon/(1.+i*i);
        i+=epsilon;
    }
    sum*(180./pi())
}

fn tan(degrees:f64) -> f64 {
    sin(degrees)/cos(degrees)
}

fn sin(degrees:f64) -> f64 {
    if degrees<0. {
        return -sin(-degrees);
    }
    if degrees>90. {
        return cos(degrees-90.);
    }
    let radians=degrees/(180./pi());
    let mut tmpsin=0.;
    let mut tmpcos=1.;
    let epsilon=radians/PRECISION;
    let mut i=0.;
    while (epsilon>0. && i<radians) || (epsilon<0. && i>radians) {
        tmpsin+=epsilon*tmpcos;
        tmpcos-=epsilon*tmpsin;
        i+=epsilon;
    }
    tmpsin
}

fn arcsin(x:f64) -> f64 {
    arctan(x/sqrt(1.-x*x))
}

fn arccos(x:f64) -> f64 {
    90.-arcsin(x)
}

fn cos(degrees:f64) -> f64 {
    sin(90.-degrees)
}

fn sqrt(x:f64) -> f64 {
    let mut max=1000.;
    let mut min=0.;
    let mut i=(min+max)/2.;
    while (max-min)>1./PRECISION {
        if i*i>x {
            max=i;
        }
        else {
            min=i;
        }
        i=(max+min)/2.;
    }
    i
}

fn pi() -> f64 {
    let mut sum=0.;
    let mut i=-1.;
    let epsilon=1./PRECISION;
    while i<1. {
        sum+=epsilon/(1.+i*i);
        i+=epsilon;
    }
    2.*sum
}

fn main() {
    println!("x\tsin(x)\tcos(x)\ttan(x)\tln(x)\tsqrt(x)\tasin\tacos\tatan");
    for i in 0..101 {
        print!("{:.4}\t",i);
        print!("{:.4}\t",sin(i as f64));
        print!("{:.4}\t",cos(i as f64));
        if tan(i as f64)<100. && tan(i as f64)> -10. {
            print!("{:.4}\t",tan(i as f64));
        }
        else if tan(i as f64)< -10. {
            print!("{:.3}\t",tan(i as f64));
        }
        else {
            print!("inf\t");
        }
        if ln(i as f64)> -100. {
            print!("{:.4}\t",ln(i as f64));
        }
        else {
            print!("-inf\t");
        }
        print!("{:.4}\t",sqrt(i as f64));
        if arcsin((i as f64)/100.)<90. {
            print!("{:.4}\t",arcsin((i as f64)/100.));
        }
        else {
            print!("90\t");
        }
        if arccos((i as f64)/100.)<90. && arccos((i as f64)/100.)>0. {
            print!("{:.4}\t",arccos((i as f64)/100.));
        }
        else if arccos((i as f64)/100.)>0. {
            print!("90\t");
        }
        else {
            print!("0\t");
        }
        print!("{:.4}\n",arctan((i as f64)/100.));
    }
    println!("pi={:.4}",pi());
    println!("rad={:.4}",180./pi());
    println!("ln(1/pi)={:.4}",ln(1./pi()));
    println!("e={:.4}",exp(1 as f64));
    println!("1/e={:.4}",exp(-1 as f64));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with the math side of this, so I'll just focus on the Rust part.

## Run [rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustfmt)

Running `cargo fmt` will autoformat your code to the Rust best practices. For example, it will convert

```rust
fn arctan(x:f64) -> f64 {
    let mut sum=0.;
    let epsilon=x/PRECISION;
    let mut i=0.;
    while i<x {
        sum+=epsilon/(1.+i*i);
        i+=epsilon;
    }
    sum*(180./pi())
}
```

to

```rust
fn arctan(x: f64) -> f64 {
    let mut sum = 0.;
    let epsilon = x / PRECISION;
    let mut i = 0.;
    while i < x {
        sum += epsilon / (1. + i * i);
        i += epsilon;
    }
    sum * (180. / pi())
}
```

Notice the spacing added.

## Run [clippy](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy)

Running `cargo clippy` will point out a few common mistakes. Let's take a look at them here.

```rust
warning: using `print!()` with a format string that ends in a single newline
   --> src/main.rs:136:9
    |
136 |         print!("{:.4}\n",arctan((i as f64)/100.));
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: `#[warn(clippy::print_with_newline)]` on by default
    = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#print_with_newline
help: use `println!` instead
    |
136 |         println!("{:.4}",arctan((i as f64)/100.));
    |         ^^^^^^^
```

As it suggests, you should replace that line with `println!`.

```rust
warning: casting integer literal to `f64` is unnecessary
   --> src/main.rs:141:28
    |
141 |     println!("e={:.4}",exp(1 as f64));
    |                            ^^^^^^^^ help: try: `1_f64`
    |
    = note: `#[warn(clippy::unnecessary_cast)]` on by default
    = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#unnecessary_cast
```

That, and the line that follows it, can be used as a float like you do everywhere else in your code. You can do `1_f64`, `1f64`, `1.0`, or like elsewhere in your code, `1.`.

## Extract repeated operations

When you print things out, you repeat the calculation a lot, and [it actually appears to have a difference in assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/Wz8r17) (although not when `#[inline(never)]` is used on `ln`?). So instead of

```rust
if arccos((i as f64) / 100.) < 90. && arccos((i as f64) / 100.) > 0. {
    print!("{:.4}\t", arccos((i as f64) / 100.));
} else if arccos((i as f64) / 100.) > 0. {
    print!("90\t");
} else {
    print!("0\t");
}
```

Prefer

```rust
let inv_cos = arccos((i as f64) / 100.);
if inv_cos < 90. && inv_cos > 0. {
    print!("{:.4}\t", inv_cos);
} else if inv_cos > 0. {
    print!("90\t");
} else {
    print!("0\t");
}
```